# Doing Week To Date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a calendar_date and user_id column.

I want to a new table where I aggregate the calendar_dates into calendar_weeks and find the difference in the sum of user_ids between each week. Essentially, this would be a combination of aggregating from daily values to weekly values, as well as a week-to-date function.

Comment: Question is not very clear so to start with there is a bigquery function like EXTRACT, In order to aggregate i.e. sum(user_id) at week level. You may  "group by  extract (WEEK FROM calendar_dates ), extract (YEAR FROM calendar_dates )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATE_TRUNC function to summarize each date to a weekly date and then group by your aggregation. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_trunc

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(calendar_date, WEEK(SUNDAY)) as calendar_week,
  user_id,
  etc...
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  calendar_week,
  user_id
```